# の or は, which particle would be a better choice in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-の

> 才能がないことはないけど、私（の or は）才能があまりすごくない。
>   "It's not that I don't have talent, but my talents aren't very cool."

Which particle would be more acceptable? I ask this because in Japanese there are phrases such as 頭がいい (smart) and in sentences with this it would be, for example:

> 彼は頭がいい。He is smart. ("his head is good.")

With は as opposed to の because while の is not technically incorrect は in that place sounds more natural to Japanese speakers. When describing attributions of something one uses "Topic は Noun が Adjective です", right? Can I use this pattern in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence, the only acceptable choice is は.

才能がないことはないけど、私の才能があまりすごくない is wrong because it lacks topics (while it's a sentence of statement that stands for general judgement or recognition about something). In other words, 私の才能は… is correct.

The second sentence is basically the same. But there's a room to suppose (unusual) situations where you use topicless sentences, like when you suddenly bump into a scene where you find someone unexpectedly smart, or when you confirm what the opponent has just said.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best not to use 私は unless this is the first sentence in a paragraph, or you're contrasting yourself with someone/everyone else.

Something like this would sound better to me:

> 才能がないことはないけど、才能があまりすごくない。

But, if you definitely want to put 私は in, I would suggest putting it up front:

> 私は才能がないことはないけど、才能があまりすごくない。

To get across the full meaning of your English expression though, I would suggest something like the following:

- 才能がない**こともない**けど、**そんなにすごいわけではないです**。
- **私は**才能がない**こともない**けど、**そんなにすごいわけではないです**。

  "It's not that I don't have talent, but my talents aren't very cool."

Comment: 「才能がないことはないけど、才能があまりすごくない。」 and 「私は才能がないことはないけど、才能があまりすごくない。」 are quite unnatural (though I guess you are already aware of that...) and, as for your 3rd and 4th sentences, I'm afraid but the latter half of them (ie. あまりたいしたものではないのです) don't really sound natural, either... I suggest something like...（私は）才能がないこともないけど / ないことはないけど / ないわけでもないけど / ないわけではないけど、そんなにすごいこともない（です）/ そんなにすごいわけでもない（です）/ たいしてすごいこともない（です）/ or just たいしたこともない（です）。

Comment: @chocolate 編集完了！これでOK?

Comment: 今思ったんですけど、「私は才能がないこともないけど、そんなにすごいわけでもない」っていうと、「すごいわけでもない」の主語が「私は」って感じになってしまいますよね。もとの、"It's not that I don't have talent, but my talents aren't very cool." では、aren't very cool の主語は my talents だから、ちょっと違いますよね。どうしたらいいでしょう？「（私には）才能がないわけではないけど、（そんなに）大した/すごい才能があるわけでもない」とか、どうでしょう？　前後の文の主語を統一したら、こういう感じになるかな～と・・

Comment: さぁ、このような口語的な内容で途中の切り替えはいいんじゃないかと思いますが、「私は才能がないこともないけど、そんなにすごい**もの**ではないです。」と言って、才能を指す「もの」で解決できるでしょうか？